# Can I hide my favourites on YouTube from the other users?

Tags: youtube, privacy

Can I hide my favourites on YouTube from the other users?

I have a normal YouTube account and I realised that everything I add to my favourites is visible to anyone. Can I hide it instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your channel page, click on "Videos and Playlists" tab and untick "My Favorites".

[image: Hide favorites from Youtube channel]

Comment: Do you know how to do this in the current YouTube version?

Comment: Answering my own question, you have to make the playlists private.

Comment: This answer is outdated, check the other answer

Answer (score 6):

For those who are wondering, even after 10 years (lol), option to hide Favorite playlist is still missing for some people.

Actually, I found out it was depending on the language you are using on YouTube. It's crazy.

So all you got to do is switch language to English (US), then go to your playlist, show it all, then you'll have the private option showing.

Comment: This is now the correct answer. It's so shameful that Youtube didn't fix such a simple problem. Youtube music doesn't allow you to use the Favourites list, when you select "Shuffle playlist" sometimes it enters in a loop of 8-10 videos, when Youtube demonetizes any of your videos it asks you to improve it but doesn't tell you why it got demonetized...

Comment: I have no idea why this works, even English (UK) doesn't show this option. Thank you though, this was bugging me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Lukmans answer doesn't work already. I've found many different solutions on the web, none working - it seems that youtube is changing this very often. So the solution as of 7.4.2013 is this:

1. open the list of your favorite videos
2. on the top of the page, click "Edit playlist"
3. above the list of the videos, tick "Make this list private"

That's it!

Comment: I think this is also outdated. There is no "Edit playlist" button there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your name icon (top right)

- Go to your channel
- Scroll down in left bar and click on Settings
- Click Status and Features
- Click on Advanced Settings. Scroll down
- Click Remove YouTube Content (could also be Hide YouTube content)

You should see the option there to hide videos. There might be an easier way, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score -1):

The lukman’s solution doesn’t work indeed, even if YouTube says your favourites are private. But if you go to your favourites, click on playlist settings and choose private, then it works!